# Google Map link does no more exist for html code

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Maps on my site with KML layers.

http://www.mynursery.be/#!carte-uk/cr8a

Since the last version of G Maps (My maps pro), the KML link i used does no more exist...

This provide the only link I can use in WIX html .

==> OLD FORMAT ( I use ) : **https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=208899208399411894595.0004d3a3b94359d611f06**

==> NEW FORMAT (Not working) : **https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?hl=fr&authuser=0&mid=zC0evbx9jVqo.kiweLp7fTy1E**

With OLD it's working, with new NO.

Is the a way to solve it? 
Is something to change in the previous html code to make it good since new version ?

tnx
LD

Comment: What were the two maps api versions you were using?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963277/how-can-i-adapt-my-google-maps-embed-code-for-v3-api-change