# How can I adapt my google maps embed code for v3 api change

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

Please find here after the full html code of my website google map.

Since the last version of "My Maps", i have quite the troubles.
Since yesterday pins are no more clickable...

The maps links are no more the same.
I'm lost; this code requires days of work without any knowledge of html coding.
I have only grabbed portions of it from different places + help of your community.

Could someone help me to reset this code to ON and help me to convert :

old AD : [https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?msid=208899208399411894595.0004daddaa7c86a50424c&authuser=0&msa=0&vps=7&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&output=kml](http://www.mynursery.be/#!carte-uk/cr8a)

in new AD : https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?hl=fr&authuser=0&mid=zC0evbx9jVqo.kFYO1Ed47KUg

almost working sample at [http://www.mynursery.be](http://www.mynursery.be/)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Exemple Google Maps JavaScript API v3</title>
    <script  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

    <div id="carte" style="width: 920px; height: 750px"></div>
    <br>
    <input type='text' id='adresse' value=''>
    <input type='submit' value='Cherchez votre ville !' onClick='rechercheAdresse();'>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
 var kml = {
    a: {
        name: "CARTE BELGIQUE",
        url: "https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=208899208399411894595.0004d24e3bd5bbd990f5d"
    },
b: {
        name: "Accueil familial subventionné",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?msid=208899208399411894595.0004dadda3622da16f8c4&authuser=0&msa=0&vps=2&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&output=kml"
    },
c: {
        name: "Accueil familial autonome",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?msid=208899208399411894595.0004dadda0922a7eaf40d&authuser=0&msa=0&vps=3&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&output=kml"
    },
    d: {
        name: "Accueil collectif subventionné",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?msid=208899208399411894595.0004daddae931fdcdc805&authuser=0&msa=0&vps=5&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&output=kml"
    },
e: {
        name: "Accueil collectif autonome",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?msid=208899208399411894595.0004daddaa7c86a50424c&authuser=0&msa=0&vps=7&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&output=kml"
    },
f: {
        name: "Magasins petite enfance",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?msid=208899208399411894595.0004dadda4c54c245991b&authuser=0&msa=0&vps=2&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&output=kml"
    },
g: {
        name: "Babysitters & Services",
        url: "https://maps.google.be/maps/ms?msid=208899208399411894595.0004dadda5def521b12ea&authuser=0&msa=0&vps=6&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&output=kml"
    },
};
        var marker;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        function initialize() {
            var toulouse = new google.maps.LatLng(50.581, 4.568);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
              minZoom: 8,
               scrollwheel: false,
                center: toulouse,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("carte"), myOptions);
        createTogglers();};


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top
function toggleKML(checked, id) {

    if (checked) {

        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
            preserveViewport: true,

        });
        // store kml as obj
        kml[id].obj = layer;
        kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
    }
    else {
        kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
        delete kml[id].obj;
    }

};

function createTogglers() {

    var html = "<form><ul>";
    for (var prop in kml) {
        html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
        " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
        kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
    }
    html += "<li class='control'><a href='#' onclick='removeAll();return false;'>" +
    "Remove all layers<\/a><\/li>" +
    "<\/ul><\/form>";

    document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
};

function removeAll() {
    for (var prop in kml) {
        if (kml[prop].obj) {
            kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
            delete kml[prop].obj;
        }

    }
};
function highlight(box, listitem) {
    var selected = 'selected';
    var normal = 'normal';
    document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected: normal);
};

function startup() {
// for example, this toggles kml a on load and updates the menu selector

var checkit = document.getElementById('a');
checkit.checked = true;
toggleKML(checkit, 'a');
highlight(checkit, 'selector1');
 };



google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});

});


function rechercheAdresse() {
            var adresse = document.getElementById('adresse').value;
            geocoder.geocode({
                address: adresse
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(12);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        clickable: false,
                        map: map
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Result not find !');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
  <style type="text/css">
.selected { font-weight: bold; }
</style>


<body onload="initialize();startup();">
<div id="toggle_box" style="position: absolute; top: 500px; right: 650px; padding: 10px; background: #fff; z-index: 5; "></div>
</html>
```

Comment: *"lost in HTML code"* - Bonus points to you for using this expression on a question about maps.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is: that code works (okay there are problems *in* the code - but nothing catastrophic). So what is the problem: embedding it in http://www.mynursery.be ?
Qu'est-ce que c'est  le problème? Le code fonctionne comme ça (ok il ya des problèmes *dans* le code -, mais rien de catastrophique). Alors, quel est le problème: l'intégration dans http://www.mynursery.be?

Comment: @Duncan OP asked his question in English. No need to translate your comments. btw I was confused, I thought: duncan, where has your rep gone?! But Duncan is not duncan ;)

Comment: Thx Duncan, I have issues with kml links. the Code is probably not perfect but working up to yesterday. I would like to know how to put the new format address of "My Maps" in this code. issues with option 4/5&6 var d/e&f) on 7 of the toggle box wich is not displaying pin's... The pins does no more show the labels ...Laurent

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for... but considering the map in new vs old and also running this code snippet you have attached in the question, When executed doesn't shows the markers that are there in the old website. They are sort of custom markers that can be added with changing the code. For that please refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom).

In the initialize() method of your code declare the markers so that they will be added in the maps. Here is a example code to display them.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this would Help!!

Comment: Hello Aniv, tnx for this nice answer. that could help me for next step. For info, all is back to normal, all pins are shown again. probably a problem coming from my host (wix / i'm a beginner) For info my pins are populated via a google sreadsheet document linked with a custom pin store at imageshack. Hope it will stay like this. But I have still the same problem of map link... if I want to add a map, i'm blocked. do you know a code adaptation for new shortened my maps address in html ?